# Python : count function does not work

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, count, continue

I am stuck on an exercise from a Coursera Python course, this is the question:

"Open the file mbox-short.txt and read it line by line. When you find a line that starts with 'From ' like the following line:
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
You will parse the From line using split() and print out the second word in the line (i.e. the entire address of the person who sent the message). Then print out a count at the end.
Hint: make sure not to include the lines that start with 'From:'.
You can download the sample data at http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt"

Here is my code:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fh:
    words = line.split()
    if len(words) > 2 and words[0] == 'From':
        print words[1]
        count = count + 1
    else:
        continue        
print "There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word"`
```

The output should be a list of emails and the sum of them, but it doesn't work and I don't know why: actually the output is "There were 0 lines in the file with From as the first word"

Comment: Have you checked the indentation of the for loop? It seems you forgot to indent the lines below the loop.

Comment: Thank you Selçuk, I've corrected the indentation but it doesn't work.. I think there are two problems: I don't know how to write the print statement to print out the list of the emails and the count does not work

Comment: Ok then, most probably the file cant be opened or is in some other format. Because your loop seems just fine. Try to add "print words" to see if the lines are getting printed and are in the format that you expect.

Comment: That is really strange, I copied your code to a py file.
Copied data from mbox-short.txt from the link you have given.

Seems to working fine for me. I got the following output.,

stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
There were 2 lines in the file with From as the first word

Comment: The point is that the output should be 27 emails and the string
"There were 27 lines in the file with From as the first word" . By the way, this is the exercise https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/pythonauto/index.php?PHPSESSID=ae422e90f54bf2a5f171cc9a5d8f9691

Comment: Selçuk , adding "print words" it prints ['Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']

Comment: Well then you are looking at another file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and downloaded the file from the link. And I am getting this output:

There were 27 lines in the file with From as the first word

Have you checked if you are downloading the file in the same location as the code file.

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
counter = 0
fh = open(fname)

for line in fh :
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From '): continue        
    words = line.split()
    print (words[1])
    counter +=1

print ("There were", counter, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Comment: You should edit your post to include an explanation of the functionality the code implements.

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

fh = open(fname)
count = 0

for line in fh :

    if line.startswith('From '): # consider the lines which start from the word "From "

        y=line.split() # we split the line into words and store it in a list
        print(y[1])   # print the word present at index 1
        count=count+1  # increment the count variable

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

I have written all the comments if anyone faces any difficulty, in case you need help feel free to contact me. This is the easiest code available on internet. Hope you benefit from my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input('Enter the file name:')
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('From'):
        linesplit =line.split()
        print(linesplit[1])
        count = count +1
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26235997)

Answer (score 0):

fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
count = 0
for i in fh:

```
i=i.rstrip()

if not i.startswith('From '): continue
word=i.split() 
count=count+1

print(word[1])
```

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('From'):  
        line=line.rstrip()
        lt=line.split()
        if len(lt)==2:
            print(lt[1])
            count=count+1
print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Answer (score 0):

My code looks like this and works as a charm:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
count = 0 #initialize the counter to 0 for the start
for line in fh: #iterate the document line by line
    words = line.split() #split the lines in words
    if not len(words) < 2 and words[0] == "From": #check for lines starting with "From" and if the line is longer than 2 positions
        print(words[1]) #print the words on position 1 from the list
        count += 1 # count
    else:
        continue
print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

It is a nice exercise from the course of Dr. Chuck

There is also another way. You can store the found words in a separate empty list and then print out the lenght of the list. It will deliver the same result.

My tested code as follows:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
newl = list()
for line in fh:
    words = line.split()
    if not len(words) < 2 and words[0] == 'From':
        newl.append(words[1])
    else:
        continue
print(*newl, sep = "\n")
print("There were", len(newl), "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

I did pass the exercise with it as well. Enjoy and keep the good work. Python is so much fun to me even though i always hated programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = input('Enter a file name: ')
count = 0
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
    for line in file_handle:
        words = line.rstrip().split()

         
        if len(words) == 0:
            continue

        if words[0] == 'From':
            count += 1
            print(words[1])

    print('There were', count, 'lines in the file with From as the first word')

except:
    print('Invalid File')
```